# NextJs 11/12, Tailwind and problem with Google Fonts

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, google-fonts

Could someone explain to me why both of the following constructions work with NextJs 11 and with NextJs 12 only the latter. If I try to import fonts in Next 12 after Tailwind it is ignored, and css from @import is not loaded.

```
/*Works with Next 11 only*/
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Julius+Sans+One&family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
```

```
/*Works with Next 11 & Next 12*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Julius+Sans+One&family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The rest of the configuration is identical. I only changed Next versions from 11.1.4 to 12.3.4. I tested it with Node 16.18.0 and 14.19.0. Nothing changes, the font imported after TailwindCSS is ignored in Next 12.

Answer (score -1):

The newly add `next/font` includes built-in automatic self-hosting for any font file. This means you can optimally load web fonts with zero layout shift, thanks to the underlying CSS size-adjust property used. Here is a snippet from the docs:

```js
import { Roboto } from 'next/font/google';
 
const roboto = Roboto({
  weight: '400',
  subsets: ['latin'],
});
 
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={roboto.className}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

See the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that's not the problem, I know many ways to load fonts that will work. The problem is that I have a lot of Next 11 projects and I'm afraid of migrating to Next 12 because it can cause font loss. I'm curious why it happens that changing the order of imports affects it. It's not caused by Tailwind Preflight (rather) because I don't change Tailwind version, only NextJs version changes.

Comment: The question was specifically about loading fonts in TailwindCSS with Next.js 11/12. `@next/font` was introduced in Next.js `v13.0.0`, later renamed to `next/font` in `v13.2.0`.